# ssis script task adding outputs for 100s of columns

Tags: c#, sql-server, visual-studio-2013, ssis, etl

I have a script task in which I need to add 100(s) of columns to its output.  Is there a way to import these output columns from a specification file instead of having to manually input them one by one or some other way I'm just not seeing?

*More info:  I read a list of case numbers from a table, use that as an input column to a script task that then calls a web service to get the case details, I then intend to output that and insert it into another table.  Loop till there are no more case numbers.  Seemed like a logical thing to do since this will need to be scheduled but copying/pasting/change datatype for all the columns in the output is very tedious and I'm not seeing anything that addresses this so I thought I would ask.*

Answer (score 2):

In Visual Studio, you can do this only manually.

Programmatically, you can do this by opening your package and adding columns (but you have to do a hard work), you can follow these links to achieve this:

- [Data flow component with number of output columns depending on input parameter. SSIS custom data flow component](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8049796/data-flow-component-with-number-of-output-columns-depending-on-input-parameter)
- [Reading DTS and SSIS packages programmatically](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/ramoji/2008/09/29/reading-dts-and-ssis-packages-programmatically/)
- [Extending SSIS Part 1 - Creating a Custom Data Flow Transformation Component](http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/Integration+Services+(SSIS)/63877/)
- [Extending SSIS Part 2 - SSIS Programmatically / Dynamically Building Packages](http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/Integration+Services+(SSIS)/64572/)

Comment: Appreciate your response.  I will investigate this.